# openvpn with proxy, Unexpected EOF: reply incomplete

Tags: openvpn, mac, http-proxy

I have an OpenVPN configuration for work that I received from my company. However, due to certain restrictions in my country, I am unable to directly reach the company's server. To overcome this, I'm using a second server as a proxy. I've configured Termius to forward traffic from my device's port 18080 to the second server. Additionally, I'm using the built-in proxy on macOS Sonoma to route all my device's traffic through that specific port.

This approach worked well on a Windows machine, but after switching to a Mac, I'm unable to connect to the company server.
I've Got: "HTTP proxy Unexpected EOF: reply incomplete"
Unfortunately, my knowledge of networking is limited. If I've omitted any crucial information for resolving this issue, please let me know.

I will appreciate any help.

ovpn config

```
client
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
proto tcp
remote COMPANY_IP PORT
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
key-direction 1
http-proxy 127.0.0.1 18080

...certs and so on...
```

open vpn log

```
[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] OpenVPN core 3.8.2connect3 mac arm64 64-bit built on Dec 19 2023 06:56:50
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] Frame=512/2112/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] NOTE: This configuration contains options that were not used:
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] Unsupported option (ignored)
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] 2 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] 6 [persist-key]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] 7 [persist-tun]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] Contacting 127.0.0.1:18080 via HTTP Proxy
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] EVENT: WAIT_PROXY ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] UnixCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to /var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock
{
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "ipv6" : false,
    "pid" : 17324
}

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] TO PROXY: CONNECT COMPANY_IP:1194 HTTP/1.0
Host: COMPANY_IP

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] TCP recv EOF
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] Proxy Error: on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] EVENT: PROXY_ERROR on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:09] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Raw stats on disconnect:
 BYTES_OUT : 60
 PACKETS_OUT : 1
 PROXY_ERROR : 1

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Performance stats on disconnect:
  CPU usage (microseconds): 2146109
  Network bytes per CPU second: 27
  Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] OpenVPN core 3.8.2connect3 mac arm64 64-bit built on Dec 19 2023 06:56:50
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Frame=512/2112/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] NOTE: This configuration contains options that were not used:
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Unsupported option (ignored)
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] 2 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] 6 [persist-key]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] 7 [persist-tun]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Contacting 127.0.0.1:18080 via HTTP Proxy
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] EVENT: WAIT_PROXY ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] UnixCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to /var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock
{
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "ipv6" : false,
    "pid" : 17324
}

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] TO PROXY: CONNECT COMPANY_IP:1194 HTTP/1.0
Host: COMPANY_IP

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] TCP recv EOF
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] Proxy Error: on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] EVENT: PROXY_ERROR on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:10] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:11] Raw stats on disconnect:
 BYTES_OUT : 60
 PACKETS_OUT : 1
 PROXY_ERROR : 1

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:11] Performance stats on disconnect:
  CPU usage (microseconds): 2256661
  Network bytes per CPU second: 26
  Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] OpenVPN core 3.8.2connect3 mac arm64 64-bit built on Dec 19 2023 06:56:50
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] Frame=512/2112/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] NOTE: This configuration contains options that were not used:
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] Unsupported option (ignored)
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] 2 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] 6 [persist-key]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] 7 [persist-tun]
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] Contacting 127.0.0.1:18080 via HTTP Proxy
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] EVENT: WAIT_PROXY ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] UnixCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to /var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock
{
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "ipv6" : false,
    "pid" : 17324
}

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] TO PROXY: CONNECT COMPANY_IP:1194 HTTP/1.0
Host: COMPANY_IP

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] TCP recv EOF
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] Proxy Error: on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete
⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] EVENT: PROXY_ERROR on 127.0.0.1:18080: HTTP proxy unexpected EOF: reply incomplete⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:12] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:13] Raw stats on disconnect:
 BYTES_OUT : 60
 PACKETS_OUT : 1
 PROXY_ERROR : 1

⏎[Jan 3, 2024, 12:09:13] Performance stats on disconnect:
  CPU usage (microseconds): 2364891
  Network bytes per CPU second: 25
  Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0
⏎
```

Comment: What kind of proxy do you use? It looks like openvpn is trying to connect to the proxy on your mac but getting a disconnect reply. Please also provide the logs of the proxy on your Mac

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.